# Inertia group of geometric Galois action

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, fundamental-groups

In I.3 of these notes: [https://www.math.arizona.edu/~swc/aws/2005/05SchnepsNotes.pdf](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Eswc/aws/2005/05SchnepsNotes.pdf) Schneps defines a homomorphism

$$G_{\mathbb{Q}}\rightarrow \operatorname{Out}(\widehat{F_2})$$

and states that the inertia groups are $\langle x\rangle, \langle y\rangle, \langle z\rangle$.  Here $x, y, z$ correspond to the loops going around $0, 1, \infty$ in the fundamental group of $\mathbb{P}^1-\{0, 1, \infty\}$, of which $\widehat{F_2}$ is the profinite completion of.

My question is, in what sense are these "inertia groups"?  And why does this imply the next line, in which Schneps gives a lifting of the outer action by

$$\sigma(x) = x^\alpha, \sigma(y) = g^{-1}y^\beta g, \sigma(z) = h^{-1}z^{\lambda}h?$$